# Animating View - compatible for iPad 3.2 and 4.2 version

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

Two views need to be resized when a button is clicked in iPad . 
I Tried it with following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    //Target Rect of the View will be given here                         
}];
```

It works fine with iPad4.2 ,but Crashes with 3.2 version(Incompatible).
On Googling found that 3.2 version supports only Animating Views (W/O Blocks)
Source:
http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:

They have mentioned its not advisable to use it for 4.0 and later 
How can I achieve animating the views for both 3.2 and 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you really need to support versions below 4.0, you can use this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; //In seconds
//Here do your stuff
int newPosY = myImage.frame.origin.y - 10;
[myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, newPosY, myImage.frame.size.width,     myImage.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That moves an `UIImageView` 10 pixels up.

Also check [`UIView` reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to see all the possibilities.

Comment: This method is not advisable for 4.0 and above . I am in need of a thing which runs in both the versions

Comment: I'm using it in a bunch of iOS 4.3 projects and also submitted apps to the App Store, what's the problem with it?